# SDL_RenderCopy() doesn't work with array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sdl, sdl-2

I've searched in internet and here and I found only 1 well post [SDL_RenderCopy with an array of Rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400544/sdl-rendercopy-with-an-array-of-rectangles). There's (as I understand) no answer, but my problem is same as there. Is any way to make this work?

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &rects[index], &sprPos);
```

Here's what debug says:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'int SDL_RenderCopy(SDL_Renderer *,SDL_Texture *,const SDL_Rect *,const SDL_Rect *)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'SDL_Rect **' to 'const SDL_Rect *'  c:\users\kushnirenko\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sdl_project\sdl_project\main.cpp 96  1   SDL_Project

2   IntelliSense: argument of type "SDL_Rect **" is incompatible with parameter of type "const SDL_Rect *"  c:\Users\kushnirenko\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SDL_Project\SDL_Project\main.cpp 96  37  SDL_Project
```

Comment: _`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`_

Comment: Your answer isn't even intuitive. OP, have you removed the ampersand from argument 3? Unless a double pointer is expected, using an ampersand isn't prime; arrays are passed by reference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem. There's a way to set an array to SDL_RenderCopy. Here it is:

```
// Sprites atlas regions
    SDL_Rect left = { sprite * 32, 32, 32, 32 };
    SDL_Rect right = { sprite * 32, 64, 32, 32 };
    SDL_Rect up = { sprite * 32, 96, 32, 32 };
    SDL_Rect down = { sprite * 32, 0, 32, 32 };

    SDL_Rect leftIdle = { 32, 32, 32, 32 };
    SDL_Rect rightIdle = { 32, 64, 32, 32 };
    SDL_Rect upIdle = { 32, 96, 32, 32 };
    SDL_Rect downIdle = { 32, 0, 32, 32 };
    // End of sprite atlas

    sprPos = { x, y, 32, 32 };

    spritesCoords[0] = left;
    spritesCoords[1] = right;
    spritesCoords[2] = up;
    spritesCoords[3] = down;

    spritesCoords[4] = leftIdle;
    spritesCoords[5] = rightIdle;
    spritesCoords[6] = upIdle;
    spritesCoords[7] = downIdle;

    sprFrame = spritesCoords[spriteIndex]; // This is solutuion.

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &sprFrame, &sprPos);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```